# Ruby on Rails: While in development, how can I send requests to 3rd party API that uses HTTPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

I am trying to use a 3rd party API that uses HTTPS, however, since I'm using localhost during development I cannot access the API. I am using the following code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

http = Net::HTTP.new("mydomain.com", 443)
http.use_ssl = true
resp, result = http.get("/secure/example")

p result
```

I receive the following error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

What can I do to use this API while in development?

Comment: *"since I'm using localhost during development I cannot access the API."* - it is unrelated to the problem that your server is running on localhost. This code to access a 3rd party API can be used without having your own server running. The problem is instead that either the 3rd party API is not properly setup or your trust store does not trust the certificate authority which issued the certificate for the 3rd party or that you are behind some SSL intercepting firewall which replaces the certificate. It is unknown what of these is actually the case but it might help if you provide the URL.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i'm attempting to reach https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ping. However I have also noticed that http works too, so I dont think i have to worry about https. 

When I test the http url with Postman, I receive the correct response which is an empty object. However when I use Rails, I get 301 "Moved Permanently" error as a response.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test third party API's using ngrok. Just start the ngrok it will give you https URL for your development server. Rest all things will work as usual. its just one command

> ./ngrok https 3000

You will be very happy to see this working without any additional configuration.

Read more about ngrok [here](https://ngrok.com/docs)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, you need to figure out if the SSL certificates are setup correctly for the target URL, and that's difficult for anyone else to debug without the URL in question.

However, you can set `Net::HTTP` to ignore the certificate error if you want to get to testing the API - it's not a good idea to leave it that way in production, as you want some level of SSL certificate verification in place ideally to avoid a Man in the Middle attack or an attack via DNS poisoning.

However, if you need to begin working with the API while you figure out any SSL issues, you can use the following in your client code:

```
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

But just to repeat, this is only really a solution to be able to begin testing and working with the API immediately, and **not** something you should leave in place long term!